# Copy QStandardItemModel to another

Tags: qt, qstandarditemmodel

Is there some way to Copy a QStandardItemModel to another QStandardItemModel?
Or must I iterate over each tem and append it to the other Model?

Comment: You should iterate over each item and COPY (not append) it to another model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An item can be owned by one model only. That is why you need to create a copy of each item and place it to another model. You can do it using method `QStandardItem::clone`.

This is an example for single column models:

```
void copy(QStandardItemModel* from, QStandardItemModel* to)
{
   to->clear();
   for (int i = 0 ; i < from->rowCount() ; i++)
   {
      to->appendRow(from->item(i)->clone());
   }
}
```

EDIT:
Use `to->removeRows(0, to->rowCount ());` instead of `to->clear();` if you want to keep header data and column sizes in linked views.

Comment: In my opinion `to->removeRows (0, to->rowCount () )` should be better then `to->clear ()`, because it doesn't remove general settings of model like headers, resize mode, etc.

Comment: @Gluttton A model doesn't have such settings as `resize mode`. Do you mean that calling `clear` forces a view to reset column sizes?

Comment: `Do you mean`, Yes, indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You could do copy of an existing item with next steps:

1. Get existing item.
2. Create new item.
3. Set necessary data roles from existing item to a new one.
4. Do the same with flags.

Or simply use [`QStandardItem::clone()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#clone) method. And reimplement it, if necessary.